# How do I solve this fraction addition problem?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

$4\frac{2}{9} + -9\frac{1}{2}$ yeilds result of $-5\frac{13}{18}$ but WolframAlpha says the answer is $-5\frac{5}{18}$

fixed.

Comment: Your pre-edit question was better for understanding what the issue was.

Comment: There was confusion. Sorry about that. The arithmetic is 4 and 2/9 plus -9 and 1/2. My answer from Wolfram is -5 and 5/18 but what I calculated was -5 and 13/18.

Comment: @kinesis was your question answered? Accept the most helpful post so we can close this if this is the case, and upvote where appropriate. If an answer satisfies you on your other posts, do the same.

Answer (score 4):

In $-9 \frac12$, the negative sign applies to the whole quantity.  Thus the calculation should be

$4 \frac29+(-9 \frac12)=\frac{38}{9}+(-\frac{19}{2})=\frac{76}{18}-\frac{171}{18}=-\frac{95}{18}=-5 \frac{5}{18}$

Comment: I do not get this answer on paper when I calculate it like this:

$4\frac{2}{9} + (-9\frac{1}{2}) = 4\frac{2*2}{9*2} + (-9\frac{1*9}{2*9}) = -5\frac{11}{18}$  did the numerator of the answer wrong, but still is $-5\frac{11}{18}$

Comment: Can you show your steps?

Comment: Steps added on previous comment. I was instructed by online tutorials and such that you do the whole parts last? I see this answer above saying that I make the second fraction a negative? 2*9 is not 38 and 1*9 is not 19...

Comment: So you have $4+\frac{4}{18}-(9+\frac{9}{18})=4+\frac4{18}-9-\frac9{18}=-5-\frac{5}{18}=-(5+\frac{5}{18})=-5\frac{5}{18}$

Comment: Oh it becomes subtraction after the $4\frac{4}{14}$ is that correct? I thought you do the fraction parts first then do the whole part math at the end.

Comment: @kinesis You can do the fraction parts first if you want (due to properties called "commutativity" and "associativity" of addition).  But you need to make sure that the signs are correct:  $-9\frac 9{18}$ equals $-9 - \frac 9{18}$, not $-9+\frac9{18}$.  The negative sign applies to both parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute $4-9=-5$ and $\frac29-\frac12=\frac4{18}-\frac9{18}=-\frac5{18}$ separately, and then add them up. Or you could compute $4\frac29 + -9\frac12=\frac{38}9-\frac{19}2=\frac{76}{18}-\frac{171}{18}=\frac{-95}{18}=-5\frac5{18}$, though the latter is probably more error prone.

Answer (score 0):

TeX \frac directive takes two arguments, but you use three in your formulas.  This probably confuses WolframAlpha.

Comment: So I did \frac{numerator}{denominator}{whole part} - What is correct? I'll fix it.

Comment: If you want to display it, just enter whole\frac{numerator}{denominator} and get $whole\frac{numerator}{denominator}$.  To get the right input for WolframAlpha - do something like whole + \frac{numerator}{denominator}

Comment: I fixed it but it didn't update correctly. it is 4 2/9 + -9 1/2

Comment: I didn't use any LaTeX formatting with WolframAlpha I just used (4 2/9) + (-9 1/2)

Comment: Wolfram's answer, (4 2/9) + (-9 1/2) = -95/18 = -5 5/18 looks right to me.  How did you get yours?

Comment: $4\frac{2}{9} + -9\frac{1}{2} = 4\frac{2 * 2}{9 * 2} + (-9\frac{1 * 9}{2 * 9}) = -5\frac{11}{18}$  Do the fractions first then do the whole number math after, right?

Comment: Well, -5 11/18 is different from -5 13/18 in your original post and both are wrong. $$4-9=-5,$$ not $-11$.

Answer (score 0):

In mixed fractions (just as in decimal ones), the sign applies to both whole and fractional parts, so

$$4\frac{2}{9} + -9\frac{1}{2}=4\frac{2}{9}-\left(9+\frac{1}{2}\right)=(4-9)+\left(\frac{2}{9}-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Since
$$4-9=-5$$
and
$$\frac{2}{9}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2\times2}{9\times2}-\frac{1\times9}{2\times9}=\frac{4-9}{18}=\frac{-5}{18}$$
the final answer is
$$-5+\frac{-5}{18}=-\left(5+\frac{5}{18}\right)=-5\frac{5}{18}.$$